# Batch editing photos to have the same background (Borders)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, batch-processing, borders

So I've a bunch of product photos and I'm required to edit them to have the same borders/background along the edges of the picture.

Is there a way to mass edit them to all have the same borders? If it is, how can I do so?

I'm using photoshop btw

Answer (score 0):

In IrfanView there is very powerful batch processing. There is probably too in Photoshop, but I do not have that here. Getting IrfanView is free and will not damage your existing Photoshop installation.

So in IrfanView you find batch processing in menu > files.

Tick special options (or something similar, mine is not English) and click "Setup".

You will find a special option just to add a frame, which you can nicely configure. So you are not the first user, with this need.

You have not told us whether you need to add the frame (have more pixels in the end) or whether you need to replace the outher (for example) 12 pixels of your exisiting dimensions. If the later, you will find instructions about negative numbers in the setup window.